# Manipulating arrays in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm, reverse

I have a problem, that i cant figure out:

In assembly language, write a function that receives a pointer to an array of integers and the size of this array, and changes the array by reversing its elements without copying the array to stack. Use the dedicated instructions and registers to work with arrays (`esi`, `edi`; `lodsb`, `stosb`, `cld`, `std`).

Example: 1 2 3 4 5 -> 5 4 3 2 1

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I dont even know where to begin...

Comment: Start by learning what the instructions lodsb, stosb, cld and std do. Then figure out how they are suited to the task and what other instructions are needed.

Comment: `lodsb` and `stosb` are not very appropriate for an array of integers. `lodsd` and `stosd` might be made to work. Dr Carter's tut may give an example of this - http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm

Comment: @FrankKotler For integers `lodsb` and `stosb` are as appropriate as `lodsd` and `stosd`, depends on the size of the integers used, which OP did not mention. 8-bit integers are big enough eg. for a regular 8-bit bitplane of a 24-bit truecolor image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversing an array with `lodsb` and `stosb` requires `cld` and `std` for every element (because one of the pointers needs to increment and the other needs to decrement), or alternatively, you can just forget `cld` and `std` and just cancel the incorrect increment (or decrement) of the other pointer by subtracting 2 (or adding 2) to it after each element.

Anyway, using `lodsb` and `stosb` in this case makes things unnecessarily complicated in my opinion. I'd use something like this:

```
    mov esi,start_address
    mov edi,end_address

    mov ecx,edi
    sub ecx,esi

x1: test ecx,ecx
    jz @ready

    mov al,[esi]
    xchg al,[edi]
    mov [esi],al
    inc esi
    dec edi
    dec ecx
    jmp x1

@ready:
```