# How to reverse the order of an array in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Right now my code is giving me 1846 backwards. I have no idea how to reverse the array to print out 1846 and not 6481. I think i need a loop to reverse it but i dont know how to go about implementing it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
.data 

enter_message:
    .ascii "Enter a binary value:\n"

enter_message_length:
    .int 22

name:
    .space 50
buffersize:
    .int 0

someLength:
    .int 50
array:
    .space 50

.text
.global _start

_start:




mov  $1846, %eax

mov $10, %ebx
    mov $0, %edi 
While_Loop:
    cmp $0, %eax                        
    je Convert_to_ASCII                 

    mov $0, %edx                        
    div %ebx                            

    add $48, %edx               
    movb %dl, buffersize(%edi)      
    add $1, %edi
    jmp While_Loop      


Convert_to_ASCII: 
    mov $4, %eax
    mov $1, %ebx
    mov $buffersize, %ecx
    mov %edi, %edx
    int $0x80

mov $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating arrays in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541679/manipulating-arrays-in-assembly)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two practical/easy options

1) Start from the end of the memory area dedicated to the target string and decrement a pointer (make sure the strings ends with an ascii zero).

```
  mov ah,[bx];
  dec bx
```

2) Use stack -- you need to do split the operation to two loops, each N iterations

- first loop: push N times
- next loop: pop N times and write to *bx++

2.1) write to temporary string (same mechanism as stack, but uses less space and more complex instructions).

2.5) use recursion

3) As this problem is fundamentally about decimal to ascii conversion, use an algorithm that works from the largest number first (this is achieved typically with trial subtractions:)

```
int biggest = 10000;
while (biggest) {
  digit='0';
  while (number >= biggest) { number -=biggest; digit++; }
  output(digit);   // tune this to skip leading zeros
  biggest/=10;  // or read next from a table
}
```